# How to set a timezone for MySql Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Tried to create new costume flag from the developer console - doesn't work.
Tied from the command line: gcloud sql instances patch  --database-flags time_zone
Doesn't work, get error: "invalidFlagName"

Answer (score 4):

There is a database flag "default_time_zone" in developer console that you can use to specify timezone offset when you create a new instance or edit an existing instance.

See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags for detailed info.

Comment: That is the global zone, not the system zone.

Answer (score -1):

The MySQL timezone tables are not populated so that flag is not supported via the `--database-flags` or web UI. If you are happy maintaining the tables yourself then ping us at cloud-sql@google.com with the setting you want and we'll manually set it.

Comment: In my case this tables are populated, but setting the default_time_zone to named timezone Europe/Berlin does not work. Does it mean that setting the timezone to +01:00 that it is not "daylight savings aware" and should be switched manually?

Comment: @Dado were you able to set the `default_time_zone` flag to a named timezone?

Comment: @LeonardoEmilioDominguez and all others searching for the same solution - in now 2022 - there is still an open issue for this problem https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74600960